# table.ajax.json().input not showing in server

Tags: datatables, laravel-datatables

I am using Yajra Datatable (https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0)

In my local If I use `console.log(table.ajax.json())` I can get `table.ajax.json().input` and base on this data I perform something. But in server this `.input` is not available and it throws error.. any idea?

[image: Local log]

Comment: I change my logic and it's working now

Comment: Do you mind putting what you did in case it helps someone else in the future?

Comment: I cannot figure out why `.input` is not available in server, so I change all my logic and I use `ajax:{data: function (d) { // my logic goes here}}`